# Consuming a SOAP Web Service

Tags: iphone, soap

I'm writing a small sample iphone application just to consume a SOAP Web service.
Can anyone point me out how to get started? or any tutorial could help?

I've already know before how to connect via the web using NSURLConnection and get the response either XML or JSON.
This is my first step to get hands dirty when connecting to a SOAP web server.. and I don't know how? and I'm not a web Dev guy..

Pls. advise. Thanks

Comment: http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/09/invoke-soap-web-service.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here is a good tutorial that can help u](http://blog.tuvinh.com/consuming-xml-web-services-in-iphone-applications/)

UPDATE :

[new link here](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43209)

Comment: That tutorial doesn't exist any more... :(

Comment: @Chris Hi I have added new link :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a static framework (still under development but working) which does SOAP/Web Service connections. You can find it at http://drekka.github.com/dXml/. It can do soap calls to web services, some very basic authentication, and has builtin xml parsing and XPath support.

Feel free to use the framework or just browse the source code for inspiration.